# NavigationDrawer hint animation (like Google Currents)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am looking for a way to give the users a hint that the navigation drawer exists.

I like the way that Google Currents hints that there is a next page, it just slides in the next page a few pixels and then removes it.

What is the best way to accomplish such an animation?

Answer (score 1):

This will only display a narrow bar on the left - like if you held your finger pressed on the border. Not sure if this is what Google Currents do, but I found this to be an elegant way to give a hint. [Source](https://gist.github.com/cuub/6029784)

```
protected void peekDrawer() {
    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
    MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 100, 0);
    m_drawerLayout.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    motionEvent.recycle();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
            MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 0, 100, 0);
            m_drawerLayout.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            motionEvent.recycle();
        }
    }, (long) (1 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS)); //change 1 to however many seconds you wish to display the hint for
}
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing your own custom ViewGroup, you should use a ViewDragHelper for this. It will take care of processing the touch events and scrolling your views for you when necessary. One you have configured it to fit your needs, you just need to call [`smoothSlideViewTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.html#smoothSlideViewTo%28android.view.View,%20int,%20int%29) on your drawer view to have it scroll to whatever position you want it to.

[Here is a nice intro to ViewDragHelper.](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/)

If you use a `DrawerLayout`, you get that kind of effect by default when the user touches the edge of the screen. I don't think you can trigger it programmatically, if that is what you want, as `peekDrawer()` is declared private inside an, also declared private, internal ViewDragHelper.Callback instance.